# Spring 4.3.0 RELEASE - auto login not redirect to home page aftre regestration

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I build web application with login & regestration from:

1. After login (username and password) - directing working
2. But after registration the "auto login" and redirect to user home page isn't working.

Why it happening?

UserController:

```
@Controller
public class UserController {

    @Autowired
    private UserService userService;

    @Autowired
    private SecurityService securityService;

    @Autowired
    private UserValidator userValidator;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/registration", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String registration(Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("userForm", new UserEntity());

        return "registration";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/registration", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String registration(@ModelAttribute("userForm") UserEntity userForm, BindingResult bindingResult, Model model) {
        userValidator.validate(userForm, bindingResult);

        if (bindingResult.hasErrors()) {
            return "registration";
        }

        userService.save(userForm);

        securityService.autologin(userForm.getName(), userForm.getPasswordConfirm());

        //model.addAttribute("user", getPrincipal());

        return "home";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/login", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String login(Model model, String error, String logout) {
        if (error != null)
            model.addAttribute("error", "Your username and password is invalid.");

        if (logout != null)
            model.addAttribute("message", "You have been logged out successfully.");

        return "login";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = { "/", "/home" }, method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String homePage(ModelMap model) {
        model.addAttribute("user", getPrincipal());
        return "home";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/admin", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String adminPage(ModelMap model) {
        model.addAttribute("user", getPrincipal());
        return "admin";
    }

    private String getPrincipal(){
        String userName = null;
        Object principal = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal();

        if (principal instanceof UserDetails) {
            userName = ((UserDetails)principal).getUsername();
        } else {
            userName = principal.toString();
        }
        return userName;
    }
}
```

CustomSuccessHandler:

```
@Component
public class CustomSuccessHandler extends SimpleUrlAuthenticationSuccessHandler {

    private RedirectStrategy redirectStrategy = new DefaultRedirectStrategy();

    @Override
    protected void handle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Authentication authentication)
            throws IOException {
        String targetUrl = determineTargetUrl(authentication);

        if (response.isCommitted()) {
            System.out.println("Can't redirect");
            return;
        }

        redirectStrategy.sendRedirect(request, response, targetUrl);
    }

    /*
     * This method extracts the roles of currently logged-in user and returns
     * appropriate URL according to his/her role.
     */
    protected String determineTargetUrl(Authentication authentication) {
        String url = "";

        Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> authorities = authentication.getAuthorities();

        List<String> roles = new ArrayList<String>();

        for (GrantedAuthority a : authorities) {
            roles.add(a.getAuthority());
        }

        if (isDba(roles)) {
            url = "/db";
        } else if (isAdmin(roles)) {
            url = "/admin";
        } else if (isUser(roles)) {
            url = "/home";
        } else {
            url = "/accessDenied";
        }

        return url;
    }

    private boolean isUser(List<String> roles) {
        if (roles.contains("ROLE_USER")) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    private boolean isAdmin(List<String> roles) {
        if (roles.contains("ROLE_ADMIN")) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    private boolean isDba(List<String> roles) {
        if (roles.contains("ROLE_DBA")) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    public void setRedirectStrategy(RedirectStrategy redirectStrategy) {
        this.redirectStrategy = redirectStrategy;
    }

    protected RedirectStrategy getRedirectStrategy() {
        return redirectStrategy;
    }

}
```

SecurityServiceImp:

```
@Service("securityService")
public class SecurityServiceImpl implements SecurityService {

    @Autowired
    private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

    @Autowired
    private UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(SecurityServiceImpl.class);

    @Override
    public String findLoggedInUsername() {
        Object userDetails = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getDetails();
        if (userDetails instanceof UserDetails) {
            return ((UserDetails)userDetails).getUsername();
        }

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void autologin(String name, String password) {
        UserDetails userDetails = userDetailsService.loadUserByUsername(name);
        UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken usernamePasswordAuthenticationToken = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(userDetails, password, userDetails.getAuthorities());

        authenticationManager.authenticate(usernamePasswordAuthenticationToken);

        if (usernamePasswordAuthenticationToken.isAuthenticated()) {
            SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(usernamePasswordAuthenticationToken);
            logger.debug(String.format("Auto login %s successfully!", name));
        }
    }

}
```

UserDetailServiceImp:

```
@Service("userDetailsService")
public class UserDetailsServiceImpl implements UserDetailsService {

    @Autowired
    private UserRepository userRepository;

    @Override
    @Transactional(readOnly = true)
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String name) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        UserEntity user = userRepository.findByName(name);

        Set<GrantedAuthority> grantedAuthorities = new HashSet<>();
        for (RoleEntity role : user.getRoles()){
            grantedAuthorities.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority(role.getName()));
        }

        return new org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User(user.getName(), user.getPassword(), grantedAuthorities);
    }
}
```

appconfig-security.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
             xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
             xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
                                http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
                                http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
                                http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-4.1.xsd">

    <http auto-config="true">
        <intercept-url pattern="/" access="hasRole('ROLE_USER')"/>
        <intercept-url pattern="/home" access="hasRole('ROLE_USER')"/>
         <intercept-url pattern="/admin**" access="hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')"/>
        <form-login login-page="/login" 
                    default-target-url="/welcome" 
                    authentication-failure-url="/login?error" 
                    username-parameter="name" 
                    password-parameter="password"
                    authentication-success-handler-ref="customSuccessHandler"/>
        <logout logout-success-url="/login?logout" />
    </http>

    <authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">
        <authentication-provider user-service-ref="userDetailsServiceImpl">
            <password-encoder ref="encoder"></password-encoder>
        </authentication-provider>
    </authentication-manager>

    <beans:bean id="userDetailsServiceImpl" class="com.searcher.service.UserDetailsServiceImpl"></beans:bean>

    <beans:bean id="customSuccessHandler" class="com.searcher.configuration.CustomSuccessHandler" />

    <beans:bean id="encoder"
          class="org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder">
        <beans:constructor-arg name="strength" value="11"/>
    </beans:bean>
</beans:beans>
```

Comment: I think that Spring Security logic doesn't executed at all because you're trying to authenticate user manually.

Comment: @SlavaSemushin well i try to follow it in Debug but it dificult.. do you have any sugesstion how to solve it?

Comment: What does CustomSuccessHandler return? Check it with debugger. Another check I would do for method determineTargetUrl, especially for the second part where through _IFs_ you define user rights. Also turn on logging on DEBUG level or even TRACE and have a look at. If you want you can attach log here as well.

Comment: I suggest to modify `UserController.registration()` method and return result of `CustomSuccessHandler.determineTargetUrl()`  instead of `"home"`.

Comment: @SlavaSemushin well how to modify the "determineTargetUrl()" and how to call her from the return becuse it needed authentication variable...

Comment: In the same way as you're setting authentication object you can get it: `SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication()` (because it's a static method, you can invoke it from any places).

Comment: @SlavaSemushin it isn`t working. when I change it it still after login direct me to the login page..